# Saying bye bye to others

Tags: word-choice

How to say bye bye (you will see that person soon) in a polite way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must say a polite way of bye bye to the person like your boss, you say 失礼します.

Comment: unless the boss is the one leaving...

Comment: What situation do you image?

Comment: For example: if you are at the office and your boss goes home for the day.  The boss is the one leaving, but you stay in the same place.

Comment: You say お疲れさまでした in this case.